# Start Service Remotely

Tags: windows-services, cruisecontrol.net, nant, remote-server

I am trying to start a few services using CCNEt and nant on a remote machine. My nant statements are like: 

The builds are successful and according to the nant results, all the services have been started. However, when I check the service manager of the remote machine, some of the services have not started. Any suggestions on why some of the services on the remote machine have not started?

Comment: How to you start the services on the remote machine? Sample code?

Comment: Do they start if you run the Nant script from the command line? If bot what are the errors?